# tikzexternalize, list-and-make, list of figures to be updated

Tags: windows, tikz-external

I am using tikz' externalize library on windows. Since my document contains graphics with `\ref`, I need to use `list and make` instead of `convert with system call`.
Since I am working on windows, I cannot use `make main.makefile`, as was also reported [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181125/pgf-externalize-with-list-and-make-on-windows).

Issuing the correct system calls is not a problem. However, I do not know how to find out which figures need to be updated since `main.figlist` seems to always list all figures. `externalize` obviously checks for whether a figure needs to be updated before issuing the system call, and I believe something like this is included in the makefile as well. 
Unfortunately I do not know how makefiles work.
Is there a way to issue this check manually, or can I get a list of outdated figures?

The generated makefiles look as follows:

```
ALL_FIGURE_NAMES=$(shell cat thesis.figlist)
ALL_FIGURES=$(ALL_FIGURE_NAMES:%=%.pdf)

allimages: $(ALL_FIGURES)
    @echo All images exist now. Use make -B to re-generate them.

FORCEREMAKE:

include $(ALL_FIGURE_NAMES:%=%.dep)

%.dep:
    mkdir -p "$(dir $@)"
    touch "$@" # will be filled later.

fig-0.pdf: 
pdflatex -enable-write18 -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "fig-0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"

fig-0.pdf: fig-0.md5
```

**Edit**: `tikz-externalize` does collect the information on whether a figure is up-to-date or not. This is obvious because after a full run, it can issue a warning if there are figures that are not up-to-date. Furthermore, if externalize is set to `convert with system call`, only those figures are updated, that were outdated. So tikz has to have a way to invoke something like an md5 check.
So instead of creating a list of outdated figures, is there maybe a way to invoke this up-to-date-check using a manual pdflatex command? Naivly put, something like `pdflatex -jobname=figure0 --check-md5`?
I am perfectly happy to start updating figures manually, but creating *all* figures everytime I change one is - to put it mildy - time consuming... There has to be a solution that is working on windows as well, I suppose?

I had a look into the tikz-externalize files, but my tex is not good enough for this...

**Edit 2**: I realize I did not make my problem clear enough, or maybe the motivation for my question.
My document includes *several* tikz pictures, many of those are very time consuming to create. I have tikzexternalize configured to consecutively number all figures in my document. Thus, I can manually invoke `pdflatex -jobname=figure0 ...`, and somehow pdflatex finds the right tikz code, although the tikzfiles are *not* named `figure0.tikz` and so on. I really can't do the manual md5 check unless I either find out where the externalize magic happens. This leaves me with the following choices:

- understand the magic (propably not going to happen anytime soon)
- find a way to invoke the tikze-md5check before typesetting
- find a way to get a list of outdated figures

Comment: I don't know how it works on Windows, but everywhere else `make` only makes things which need remaking. It doesn't matter that they are listed. Unless you force a remake, `make` will check if they need remaking before doing so. Have you tried to see if it does the right thing?

Comment: Since I cannot run the makefile, I cannot test this. So, basically the up to date check is done by make?

Comment: Yes. That's how `make` works. You can force it to remake things which don't look as if they need to be remade, but to do that you have to override the default.

Comment: But tikz externalize seems to have a way to do this check as well. After a full run of pdflatex the library prints out whether all images are up to date or not. So this information should be somewhere...

Comment: Why can't you do what `make` does and just look at the modification times for the files? If the `.md5` is newer than the `.pdf`, then the image needs remaking. Otherwise not.

Comment: I didnt realize this is what make does :D
But I guess the md5 sum is updated with every run of pdflatex, whether the sum changed or not?

Comment: No. Not according to the TikZ manual. `The MD5 is compared against the MD5 of the previous run, which, in turn, will be written into an extra file with the extension .md5. This file will be modified if and only if the MD5 comparison indicates a difference. ` Otherwise `make` would remake all the figures after a recompilation, too.

Comment: I see! Now that could certainly be used to create something similar to a manual makefile. Thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: This is why the Makefile you posted lists the `.md5` as the trigger for the `.pdf`.

Comment: Also, not according to the time stamps for `md5` files in directories of projects I recompiled over weeks or months. E.g. for one project, I have one for 4th Feb and the rest for 17th Feb. But I last recompiled on this machine on 24th Feb. (And it is very unlikely I commented out the images involved in this project as some are used repeatedly throughout.)

Comment: I've deleted some of my earlier comments. I didn't realise initially that you didn't know `make` worked this way or what the `Makefile` meant.

Comment: Have you installed `make`? The support for `win32` appears to be actively maintained (a commit pertaining to this platform occurred 5 weeks ago). The current version is 4.2.1. I know nothing about installing this kind of thing on Windows, although I'm aware that MS does not provide users with development tools. (Because that would be far too empowering? Because the tools suck? Because they make more money this way?) But often projects make binaries available for Windows for precisely this reason, even if they provide none for other platforms. If not, surely somebody must provide them?

Comment: You need a compiler, but I'm guessing that one of the 'officially supported' compilers will be available in binary form. If you download the archive for 4.2.1, there is a `README.W32` which explains what you need and where you can obtain it. [I don't know how much this stuff matters to you, so this may just be more hassle than running the commands manually. But, if not, it seems that you do have some reasonable options to install GNU's `make`.]

Comment: @cfr the latest version of GNU make I found a few days ago still had the bug that was reported in the Q I linked. I really did not want to compile it myself, or install Cygwin...

Comment: Yes. If there's no binary available, there's not much else you can do :(. However, I think you've now got a solution to this particular problem, so perhaps the lack of `make` is not that terrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This here *may* address the problem at hand, although I might have missed some point.

First, your basic assumption that you "need to use `list and make` instead of `convert with system call`" is outdated: 
Some decent version (*) of the `external` lib *comes with support* for `\ref` inside of pictures *relying on the default `convert with system call`*. The solution is based on a detection that the image contains an undefined reference. It then writes some special marker into the image's `.dpth` file. Later-on, this marker is read and the image will be reconverted during `\end{document}`, assuming that the reference is available then.

Thus, one solution to the problem "I need to handle `\ref` inside of my external images" might be to update to a decent version of the `external` lib and use `convert with system call`. Such a decent version is probably shipped with `pgfplots`, i.e.

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

might do the trick.

(*) At the time of this writing, the "decent version" needs to be defined properly:

1. the `external` library as it is shipped and documented in the current stable PGF 3.0.1a does *not* contain the mentioned feature.
2. a copy of the `external` library is shipped with `pgfplots`. This one is *always* at least as recent as the version shipped with PGF. At the time of this writing, it is more recent and comes with the mentioned feature. If you write `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}`, the code checks if the version available as part of PGF happens to be more recent. If so, the version of PGF will be used. If not, the copy shipped with `pgfplots` will be used. Eventually, both will be in sync, but PGF's release cycle is way longer. That means that you are always better off with `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` (at the cost of loading `pgfplots`).

---

That said, if you want to know which figures need to be remade due to a changed MD5, you can check if the file `fig-0.pdf` is *older* than the file `fig-0.md5`.

Note that the line

```
fig-0.pdf: fig-0.md5
```

in the Makefile does the same trick. And running LaTeX on the main file will update the `.md5` file if and only if the MD5 has changed.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320584/tikzexternalize-list-and-make-list-of-figures-to-be-updated?noredirect=1#comment785639_320584, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320584/tikzexternalize-list-and-make-list-of-figures-to-be-updated?noredirect=1#comment785644_320584. The first part of your answer is interesting. Has the manual not been updated? Or are you suggesting the OP use a development version of TikZ not yet on CTAN? Page 609 of the manually clearly says this won't work with `convert with system call`. ...

Comment: @cfr, same here, `\ref` in a tikz image does not work with a recent updated MikTex 2.9

Comment: @Christian Feuersänger, I will try your approach. I am not that good with windows command line scripts, or PowerShell for what its worth, so I will probably take some time until I have a script ready that compares time stamps. Stay tuned.

Comment: I still find it difficult to understand that tikz externalize does not provide a decent way of dealing with `list and make` under windows...

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I missed part of this answer as it referred to *the* `external` library, which I assumed meant the `external` library rather than some other one. This does work. Also, excuse my very minor format edits. I only did this so that the system would allow me to undo my down-vote. (Really, the system should recognise that people screw up sometimes and need to undo their mistakes!). Many apologies. @Dux This *does* work. ***Use the `pgfplots` `external` library.*** It is too bad this is not incorporated back into the TikZ library.

Comment: Just to make things clear: _The external library in pgfplots and tikz are in sync_. The _only_ reason why pgfplots comes with a copy is that pgfplots has a release cycle of about 6-7 months whereas tikz has a release cycle of 2 years. That means: the next version of tikz will have the very same version.

Comment: ... that means that I have used undocumented insider information in this answer. But you will forgive me since the alternative would be to wait for the next release of tikz.

Comment: @Dux you are right, an alternative for `list and make` under windows would be great. Since I am author and maintainer of the `external` lib, I accept this as feature request.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger, I made the same mistake @cfr did, and did not properly read your answer. You are right, using pgfpltots' external library indeed solves the `\ref` problem. That is why I will accept your answer. And I should really have noticed that you are the maintainer of this lib, your name is on the manual of pgfplots :D
Thank you very much for your work, and the accepted feature request is much appreciated!

Comment: I have edited the answer to stress (and explain) the fact that one has to use the copy shipped with `pgfplots`.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger, your claim that "the external library in pgfplots and external are in sync" is confusing. It seems to be precisely *because* they're not in sync that this it's required to use the copy shipped with pgpflots intstead of that which is shipped with TikZ.

Comment: You are right... they would be in sync of both had about the same release cycle, but pgfplots has a much smaller release cycle and the copy shipped with pgfplots is better maintained.

Answer (score 2):

I've had several years of success using Windows 7 (and more recently using Windows 10) with `tikz externalization` under `mode = list-and-make`.

I cannot comment (not enough points), hence this answer instead, in hopes of resolving what may be some misconceptions such as

> Since I am working on windows, I cannot use make main.makefile, as was also reported in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181125/pgf-externalize-with-list-and-make-on-windows/181259#181259),

where the linked question was closed based on the author's thought that

> It seems that only I have the problem.

(I think I, too, experienced the same or similar problem).

The culprit appeared to me to be differences in the behavior of the `cat` command between linux and what was available in my case by default on Windows: one variant put a space between concatenations, the other produced a newline (I can't remember which did what).  I installed [`RTools`](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) (with `RTools` ahead of related components on the Windows system path) so that the `cat` command on Windows changed to behaving as the linux version (I had issues I didn't understand with `cygwin`), and problems related to `main.makefile` and `main.figlist` (mentioned in the closed linked question) resolved, and everything worked.  (I've been using `externalization` with `mode = list-and-make` on Windows for documents of classes `beamer`, `article` and `tufte-handout`, with the only hickup being that I cannot get the `tufte` class to work with `lualatex` as the `externalization` engine (have to stick with `pdflatex`), which is a different issue).