# Is it possible to use GPU acceleration on compiling large LaTeX documents?

Tags: graphics, compiling, performance

Surprisingly, I haven't found much information on this topic, except for [Tips for choosing hardware for best LaTeX compile performance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103565/tips-for-choosing-hardware-for-best-latex-compile-performance), which states that compilation time mostly depends on how high the clock speed per core of the CPU is.

However, what if I have a lot of graphics (assume both TikZ and PDF figures) and moderately complex text? Can I use a dedicated graphics chip to improve the compilation time?

In general, is there a way to make use of GPU when compiling LaTeX projects?

Comment: Doubt it. The sort of processing that is required to compile graphics code is not the sort of process that a graphics card does.

Comment: Not related to GPU usage, but to improve compilation time, you could also use formats (building your own based on your preamble). This way as long as you didn't change your preamble it doesn't have to be compiled again. Especially when you're using big packages (like TikZ) this saves some time.

Comment: I do not think so, since GPUs are only highly efficient for specific tasks. However if you have a lot of documents parallel compilation on a multicore machine may give some advantage: https://www.uweziegenhagen.de/?p=3501

Comment: Since TeX does not really know anything about graphics instructions of a GPU there is limited advantage of trying to run the TeX compiler on GPU

Comment: nah, just select a good package.

Comment: It shouldn't matter much how high the compile time is for the final pdf, and often you only care about intermediate runs to check how some things you added/change affect the overall document. If you have a  document where this takes so long, then you might have other options: you could use placeholders (there should be packages for that) for images, or since the document probably is so big, you can split it into multiple parts, so you could compile the parts on their own, which should be near enough to check whatever you want while working on it, and only once in a while do a full compile.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen You'd be surprised what GPUs can do especially Nvidia Cuda Core programming. 
https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/gpu-accelerated-applications/catalog/ 

I recently learned it's uses are way more flexible than people think. I'm note 100% sure about LaTeX but I don't think it should be ruled out so quickly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This question can be understood in two ways:

1. You want to compile your LaTeX document using CPU and GPU: This is effectively the same question as if you would like to use another core (i.e. multi-core setup) for compiling the document, that's not possible.
2. You want to use the GPU exclusively: I doubt that this would be highly effective as usually GPUs have some optimized operations, mostly concerning graphics, but are not that much faster for "ordinary" tasks (they may even be slower for some operations). Apart from that it would be a really hard task to use the GPU instead of the CPU as you would need to translate TeX's CPU instructions into GPU instructions beforehand and have your OS (and probably also graphics driver) allow these operations.

What you can do in your situation:

- If you have many TikZ figures you can use externalization which makes compiling faster (except for the first time). Just including PDFs is very fast.
- You could also create a format which would "pre-compile" the preamble in some way and therefore speeds things up (except when creating the format, thanks to Skillmon for pointing this out).

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies a lot. So, one can *theoretically* use a single GPU core instead of CPU for compilation?

Comment: @andselisk You would have to convince the OS to do so and maybe your graphics driver won't allow it. I have never tried to implement that.

Comment: @andselisk this wouldn't make sense though. I doubt a single GPU core can be faster than a single CPU core for TeX compilation.

Comment: @Skillmon I agree, hence I put "*theoretically*":) I'm still wondering what prevents LaTeX compilers from fully using multi-core processors. Then graphics chips would be far more superior since they have much more cores to run in parallel. If you know where I can read about this, please feel free to point me in that direction.

Comment: @andselisk What prevents multi-threading is simple: The page shipout involves many things including counters, page numbers, running headers etc. It would be hard to do this in parallel. If you do not include those parts you can split your document into several ones with a common preamble and then do a multi-threaded compilation (and at the end merge all those), but a normal TeX typesetting process is very linear

Comment: @andselisk simply think of the time when TeX was created. Also much of the layout depends on stuff computed prior to that, which isn't really the point of multi-threading.

Comment: You can speed up the process even on the first run with `mode=list and make` and compiling the `tikzpicture`s in parallel. I reduced first-time compilation of my thesis from about 90 minutes to 13 minutes on a 12-core machine. Compiling the document with all `tikzpicture`s present then takes about another 100 seconds.
It's also quite handy because you can build individual `tikzpicture`s manually by just issuing a `make <tikzpicture-filename>`  (might need to be forced if nothing has changed). Gives you basically a `standalone`-like setup. Unsure on portability though.
See p.614f in pgfman.

Comment: @alpenwasser I guess the externalization point of first time being not reduced is cpu time which isn't enhanced in your setup either. But introducing `make` is a good point. Also pre-converting .png files and the like to PDF is a huge improvement (depending on the png file).

Comment: @alpenwasser 90 minutes to compile?? then you must be doing something very unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: @mathreadler That might well be, but I'm really not doing anything extravagant. I'm just parsing `csv` files and plotting the results with pgfplots (which, uhm, might be inefficient?). It's about 140 csv files, 60 `tikzpicture`s and a few hundred thousand data points. Since I rarely had to compile the entire thing from scratch and got excellent output quality, I'm not complaining, though if somebody has suggestions for optimization, I would be curious (though it might be a tad off-topic for this question).

Comment: @alpenwasser : Of course if you re-run heavy algorithms to generate all the pictures all the time as part of the script it will take time. Maybe you can decouple the generation of the images from the typesetting process so you only rebuild images if you have changed the process or data dependent on generating them?

Comment: @mathreadler I have added some new benchmark numbers and background information to my post. Most of the time, the externalized pictures don't change once I've made them, so I actually rarely need to recompile them all. So yes, quite agreed, only regenerating the images when there has been change is advisable (hence using `tikzexternalize` in the first place).

Comment: There’s a misconception in the answer and the comments: you cannot simply substitute the CPU for the GPU. Even if the operating system allowed it. They use different instruction sets and have a different hardware architecture. They don’t speak the same language. In order to run a program on the GPU, it needs to be specifically programmed and compiled to target that GPU.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Oh well, I see I forgot to add this to the OS and driver comment. Thanks. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 27):

## tikzexternalize in parallel

I thought I might as well expand my answer a bit regarding the parallelization of externalizing `tikzpicture`s. I recommend reading the section of pgfman for more details (p.607 onwards).

**Disclaimer**: I'm a Linux guy; haven't tried this on other platforms. But [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181125/pgf-externalize-with-list-and-make-on-windows) suggests that it can be done, apparently.

Anyway: Let's make a very simple example document with quite a few `tikzpicture`s in it. Note the `mode=list and make` in the call to `tikzexternalize`. That's the important bit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz-,mode=list and make]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,2) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,3) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,1) -- (7,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,-1) -- (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Run

```
pdflatex myfile
```

or your engine of preference.

Then you will have a new file in your directory, `myfile.makefile`. Execute that with

```
make -j<PARALLEL_JOB_COUNT> -f myfile.makefile
```

And that will build your `tikzpicture`s in parallel batches of `<PARALLEL_JOB_COUNT>` For four, this would be

```
make -j4 -f myfile.makefile
```

Use your number of cores as a guideline for how many parallel jobs to run.

If all  has gone well, you can then compile your document again and include all the `tikzpicture`s:

```
pdflatex myfile
```

And all should be well.

As I mentioned in the comment to TeXnician's answer, I was able to cut down compilation time for my thesis (lots of `pgfplot`s) from about 90 minutes to roughly 13 on a clean directory (well, 16 minutes, actually, counting the two 90-second runs before and after generating the `tikzpicture`s, but still -- pretty impressive gain, methinks). Of course, more cores are better here; I have 12 on that machine.

Aside from compilation time, another thing I found hugely beneficial to this process came about in the workflow though: You can easily force a rebuild of individual tikzpictures from the commandline. If you have your individual `tikzpicture`s in separate files, this means you basically get a very similar workflow as if you'd used `standalone` for your `tikzpicture`s. So, for example, if we want to build `tikz-main-figure5.pdf` in this case, we can issue:

```
make -B -f main.makefile tikz-main-figure5.pdf
```

The `-B` option forces `make` to rebuild the target -- usually needed in these cases if you change your `tikzpicture` without then compiling your main document again, because then the `m5dsum` will not get updated and `make` will think nothing has changed. You can of course also just delete the `.pdf` file and recompile without the `-B` switch, but this is how I usually did it during those long hours late at night when I was fiddling with my plots and trying to get them to look right. I had the Ti*k*Z pdf open in one window, and the editor with the source code in another, and a shortcut for the recompilation, and that was really quite convenient to work with.

---

## GPU note

Leaving aside the things which have already been mentioned about the compilation of a TeX document being a heavily serialized job in many ways, you would probably need to write your own TeX implementation to run on your GPU, or a wrapper which can run the x86 TeX on your GPU. Neither of these are what I'd call a trivial process, and given that in many scenarios the benefits would probably be marginal (or negative) at best, I doubt it's worth it.

---

## Update: Benchmarks and Background

Since a compile time of 90 minutes seems as ludicrous to me as it probably does to most here, I've dug up the project again and have been fiddling around with it a bit. The current numbers are as follows:

- Building all `tikzpicture`s from scratch (most of which are `pgfplot`s), **sequentially**: 57 minutes
- Building the `tikzpicture`s with 12 jobs in **parallel**: 7:30 minutes

The whole shebang consists of

- 61 output pdf files for the `tikzpicture`s
- 256,000 lines of CSV data, 130,000 of which is 3 columns, the rest mostly 2 columns
- 237 `\addplot` commands, the data for which is usually read in via `\pgfplotstableread` commands

At the moment, I see two primary areas for optimization. Since they are also generally valid for speeding up the compilation of `tikzpicture`s, I hope this is still sufficiently on-topic to mention:

- Reducing the number of data points, and
- removing any `filter/.code` commands, moving their work to the tool which generates the data in the first place.

So:

- Yes, there is potential for optimization here.
- I'm fine with that. My point was that parallel compilation of `tikzpicture`s can bring significant reductions in overall compile time and is relatively easy to accomplish if you're not commandline-averse.
- Also, it's not as bad as it sounds, since I rarely have to compile all `tikzpicture`s from scratch -- usually I just update one thing, and then the whole document compiles in about a 40 seconds (could be further reduced with `\includeonly`, but I usually don't bother). Or if I'm working on a specific `tikzpicture`, I only ever need to rebuild that, which is also quite acceptable (see the workflow notes above).

If anyone wants to have a go at it themselves (or be appalled at some LaTeX heresy I probably committed), the document can be found [here](https://github.com/alpenwasser/pitaya/tree/master/doc/report) (full pdf versions available in the [snapshots](https://github.com/alpenwasser/pitaya/tree/master/doc/report/snapshots) directory). It's a bit of a convoluted setup because I also use a separate `build` directory and getting that to work properly with `tikzexternalize` is a bit of a story in and of itself. But if anyone wants to have a look at an actual use-case for a non-tiny project with `tikzexternalize`, it might be of interest.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long does lualatex take to compile your thesis?

Comment: @Aditya Alas, I have not yet been able to make it compile with lualatex (getting an error `command \attribute already defined`). I have added updated compile times for `pdflatex` to the post though.

Comment: I feel obliged to point out (as you mentioned you're a Linux guy) that you missed a golden opportunity to write "The whole #!" before the second set of bullet points in your update ;-)

Comment: @tonysdg I considered it, but thought it might feel a bit alienating to those unfamiliar with it. I am quite glad that somebody noticed though. ;-)

Comment: Let me say that it is a beautifully typeset thesis!

Comment: I'm somewhere between liking and hating your thesis layout. While the plots and most of the rest look very good, I dislike the eye-candy of your chapter titles. They look good but at the same time are annoying :)

Comment: @Skillmon No worries, one's mileage will vary, totally fair enough. It is admittedly rather more decorative than what one usually finds in such documents. While I'm mostly happy with how it came out, if I ever use this code again, I will probably tone it down somewhat to make it less ... intrusive, for lack of a better term. But at some point I had to stop tinkering with the design and actually write the bloody thing (well, my parts of it, anyway). ;-)

Comment: Wow that is the most beautiful and detailed bachelor thesis I have ever seen, that could easily be a master thesis.